# Delphi 10 Seattle IDE issue: no hint after ( on a function/proc

Tags: delphi

I installed Delphi 10 Seattle on 2 machines. I am having the same issue on both.

When I'm typing a function/proc and type the `(`, a hint used to popup in previous versions showing the function parameters and which step you were on, but this is no longer working. Was it removed?

Comment: No. But possibly, it's conflicted with some IDE extensions. You can show it by press Ctrl+Shift+Space.

Comment: No, it's not removed. Works fine here.

Comment: Only using DDevExtensions (used it on all previous versions as well though without this issue). I will try after I remove it. thanks. edit: issue persists after removing it.

Comment: This functionality is flaky. Start a new project and see if it works.

Answer (score 7):

No, it was not removed. It works fine for me.

[image]

This feature is called *Code Parameters*, and it's part of *Code Insight*. There are a few common reasons for *Code Insight* to not work properly:

- It's been disabled. Go to *Tools->Options->Editor Options->Code Insight*, make sure the *Source file type* combobox says *Pascal Files*, and confirm that the *Code Insight* options are enabled:

[image: Code Insight Options dialog]

- Errors in your code prevent the IDE's compiler (aka the *kibbitz compiler, which is different from the normal compiler and the command-line compiler) from interpreting your code properly. Comment out the line you're currently working on, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to compile, and fix any errors it reveals, and then try again.
- The method, function or procedure for which you're expecting code parameters help isn't in scope for the kibbitz compiler. Add the proper units to your uses clause to make the function or procedure available.
- You've set the longest delay in *Code Insight* options (in the same location described above and displayed in the image of the configuration dialog), and you've not waited long enough for them to appear. Lessen the delay using the thumb on the trackbar  in that dialog. You can also manually invoke the feature by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: In addition to all of this, sometimes code/error insight just breaks and fails to work.  Sometimes I'll return to the IDE from a debug session and the code will be littered with false errors and code insight doesn't work.  A recompile will usually fix it, as you say, but it's not always because of errors - I've often seen this even with very clean code, no weird circular references, no warnings, no errors.

Comment: No luck. Code Insight options are as default like in the screenshot. A simple new project with ShowMessage( still doesn't work, as soon as I type the ( I get an error on the left Structure pane with "Expected ')' but received END at line 28 (28:1)"

Comment: Ignore errors you see in the Structure Pane. That's Error Insight (which uses yet *another* compiler), and it's been bug-riddled since it's release. It's usually one of the first things I disable when I install the IDE. (Which I see by the image I posted I haven't done on this machine yet - time to fix that oversight now.) As far as the lack of luck, it's clearly something on your machine that's causing the problem, because it works for me and others according to their comments. I can't tell you what it might  be, because I can't see your machine from where I'm sitting. :-)

Comment: Ah well :c I will try with a fresh Windows install and see. The manual trigger works though (Ctrl+Shift+Space)